# To get "et al" in the text when a reference is cited with natbib and IEEEtranN

Tags: natbib, ieeetran, author-number

I have loaded `\usepackage[round, sort]{natbib}` and  `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}`

my .bib is:

```
@misc{kinaSUR,
    author = "{Barnett, S., Etchells, D., Weidelich, Z. and Tomkins,M}",
    title = {{Canon T3i Review }},
    howpublished = {\url{http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/T3I/T3IA4.HTM}},
    note = {{Online}; Accessed January 2015} ,
    year=2011,
}
```

when I cite (with `\citep{kinaSUR}`) I get: Barnett, S., Etchells, D., Weidelich, Z. and Tomkins,M in the text body of my report instead of Barnett,S. et al.
How can you manage to get the citation right?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You should remove the curly braces from the `author` field, replace the *connecting* commas with the keyword `and`, and re-run BibTeX and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra pair of curly braces around the contents of the `author` field tell bibtex that the piece has a single "corporate" author, rather than four distinct authors. Remove the curly braces, and replace the two "connective" commas with the keyword `and`. The author field should look like this:

```
author = "Barnett, S. and Etchells, D. and Weidelich, Z. and Tomkins, M.",
```

Be sure to re-run BibTeX and to run LaTeX twice to propagate the changes fully.